# Keep aspect ratio inside a flex parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I know there's a lot of topics talking about aspect ratio but I couldn't find any answer fitting for my problem.

Here's my problem:

I want to have a div with perfect square aspect ratio inside a flex parent with a 100% height.

Here's my actual HTML:

```
<article class="article">
     <header class="article-header">
          <div class="article-header__user">
               <div class="article-header__user-color"></div>
               <p class="article-header__user-name">Damiano Mondaini</p>
          </div>
          <div class="article-header__more">
               <a href="#" class="article-header__more-share-link">
                    <i class="article-header__more-share-icon">S</i>
               </a>
          </div>
     </header>
</article>
```

Here's my actual CSS:

```
.article {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #134B5F;
}

.article-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.article-header__user {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.article-header__user-color {
    background: red;
}
```

Note:

- `<div class="article-header__user">` is the flex parent
- `<div class="article-header__user-color">` is the div that should be a square
- I don't want to use JS

Thanks in advance

Comment: but what is happening now then? where is the problem?

Comment: Could you turn your code into a SO code snippet?

Comment: i think your problem is that `<div class="article-header__user-color">` doesn't showup right?

Comment: @RamondeVries RIght now nothing is happening because ```<div class="article-header__user-color">``` doesn't have any height or width. But I wan't it to be a square with 100% height.

Comment: setting `100% height` will not work, since the rest of the code is missing height too, the height you see is based on padding

Comment: @RamondeVries Ok so then my best option is to set a hard coded height and width and edit it with media queries for a correct responsive?

Comment: yes, or change the article's code so it has height relative to screen size or something

Answer (score 0):

try like this

**HTML**

```
<article class="article">
     <header class="article-header">
          <div class="article-header__user">
               <div class="article-header__user-color">
               <p class="article-header__user-name">Damiano Mondaini</p>
          </div>
          <div class="article-header__more">
               <a href="#" class="article-header__more-share-link">
                    <i class="article-header__more-share-icon">S</i>
               </a>
          </div>
          </div>
     </header>
</article>
```

**css**

```
.article {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #134B5F;
}

.article-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.article-header__user {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-header__user-color {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you were missing `width` and `height` on the `<div class="article-header__user-color">`
This should be the working code:

```css
.article {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #134B5F;
}

.article-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.article-header__user {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.article-header__user-color {
    background: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
     <header class="article-header">
          <div class="article-header__user">
               <div class="article-header__user-color"></div>
               <p class="article-header__user-name">Damiano Mondaini</p>
          </div>
          <div class="article-header__more">
               <a href="#" class="article-header__more-share-link">
                    <i class="article-header__more-share-icon">S</i>
               </a>
          </div>
     </header>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wasn't explicit enought. I want ```<div class="article-header__user-color"></div>``` to be a square with a 100% height

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that article or its children haven't any specified height. I'll give my article's header a hard coded height and it will work. Thanks everyone.